# Tag request: tableau-api

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

Tableau ([tableau visualization software](http://tableausoftware.com/)) already has a tag: [tableau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableau), but there are two main groups (users, developers) and another tag may be merited.

I propose [tableau-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableau-api) that is for developers who may have zero experience with the visualization software.

My recent self-answer that I think would benefit from [tableau-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableau-api): [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247734/file-too-short-with-tableau-data-extract-api-python-and-linux/22247735#22247735), and this tag is something that I would closely follow.

By searching for 'tableau api', [42 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tableau%20api) are found, compared to [785 for 'tableau'](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tableau) - although french coders may use this term for 'table' (i.e. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242269/php5-mysqli-object-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function))

Here are some other examples: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450696/importing-a-table-from-an-html-file-directly-to-tableau/14470450#14470450), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684028/tableau-extract-api-with-multiple-tables-in-a-database), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049134/looking-for-middleware-form-mongodb-to-tableau/15602507). Because the linux API was just released, I expect more questions to start to appear.

Comment: seems reasonable, especially considering the language possibilities

Comment: There are only 157 questions in the main tag.  A subtag would *dilute the potential user base*.  This is probably a bad idea.

Comment: The user based is very divided between users (think pie charts) and developers, and Tableau has recently expanded the API to work with the server product as well as the data engine.

Answer (score -5):

The Tableau API is the only thing that is on-topic here, since this is a programming Q&A site. Using an online, interactive, data-visualization software is clearly outside this site's scope.

I've now created the [tableau-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableau-api) tag, and merged the other [tableau-*] tags into it.

There were—and still are—an *awful* lot of off-topic questions with the [tableau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableau) tag. We're probably going to need to have a cleanup-a-thon at some point to deal with this.

Comment: I think it's a little more nuanced than this.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399675/2573061

Comment: @C8H10N4O2, I agree that this answer is too much false or correct or black/white approach. I think there is a lot of nuance to this topic. This is clearly a black-or-white fallacy!

Comment: I know I'm late to the game. I understand the reasoning behind the decision (not that I agree with it) but if the Tableau data visualization tool is out of scope of SO, wouldn't the powerquery and powerbi tags fall under the same guidelines? There are hundreds of powerquery and powerbi questions which are not programming related; instead, they are related to how to use the tool. I see your last statement acknowledging that problem. It feels like if these tools are inappropriate for SO, clean them all up. Us end users only see inconsistency in what is allowed and what isn't.

Comment: @Sam It may very well be that there are other inappropriate questions on Stack Overflow. With only 20-25 moderators, it is impossible for us to handle *everything*. If you want to propose clean-up of the powerquery and/or powerbi tags, please post a new Meta question.