# Undo recent tag renaming action - [tableau] became [tableau-api] on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, status-declined, tags, retag-request

It looks like someone tried to create a new Stack Overflow tag [tableau-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableau-api) (which is a good idea) but instead renamed the existing tag [tableau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableau) to become [tableau-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableau-api) instead (which is a bad idea)

In addition to renaming the tag, they added a bit of *text* to the description which shows that intent.

Can someone with enough rep to make the change, please rename the tag from [tableau-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableau-api) to [tableau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableau), so that all the old connections are preserved — and then add the new tag [tableau-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableau-api)?

I’m active on that tag, but don’t have the rep to rename a tag apparently.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251957/tag-request-tableau-api

Comment: Could you clearly explain why this is a problem and what "connections" are lost in your question?

Comment: @Alex Bakemore, I support you that the merge of tableau tag -> tableau-api doesn't make sense at all. Tableau as a tool today is way beyond only visualization and IMO deserves a separate tag for us users to be able to help each other on various topic considered Tableau. I think Tablaeu as a programming language can be challanged. Is Excel (worksheets) also a programming language? Excel formulas?

Answer (score 10):

There are questions that are Tableau related and might be on-topic but should not be tagged [tableau-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableau-api).  Offhand, I could think of:

- [tabpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tabpy) and [rserve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rserve), which already have tag wikis.
- Questions that seek to debug custom SQL data sources in Tableau.
- Questions about Tableau formulas in calculated fields.  We already have [excel-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-formula), and Tableau formulas (custom metrics and user-defined functions) would seem to be as on topic (if not more, since they're dependent on attribute names and not cell references, and the syntax is kind of a cross between a SELECT statement and an excel formula).  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327021/tableau-calculated-field-formula) is an example of such a question.  It should not get [tableau-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableau-api), but we should either tag it with something like [tableau-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableau-formula)... or we should deem Tableau formulas to be off-topic (unless they use TabPy or RServe) and close as off-topic.

Comment: Do you think that such questions should be tagged [[tag:tableau]]? Or merely that they are *also* on topic, but have their own tags, as you mentioned here?

Comment: @CodyGray I support the decision to un-tag "tableau" but not necessarily to re-tag everything as "tableau-api."  Some of the questions tagged tableau-api should probably be   tagged tableau-formula (if that's on topic) or something else.  If there's some consensus around that I'm happy to help with the retagging.  Also, I don't know much about the tableau API, but if there's no "tableau" tag then we should edit the "tableau-api" tag wiki to explicitly explain what's blatantly off topic for SO.  Or maybe blacklist "tableau".

Comment: Is tableau sql too different from standard sql flavors?

Comment: I don't see why writing formulas for data visualization software should be on-topic. That's not programming; it's regular usage of pre-packaged consumer software. Yes, perhaps the [tableau-api] tag wiki should be rewritten. I'm happy to have someone knowledgeable about this do so. Blacklisting tags is not an option anymore, which is part of why I chose to do a merge instead. Having it automatically rename itself is about the best option we have for deterring incorrect tagging.

Comment: @Braiam there's no tableau sql flavor.  It's whatever flavor RDBMS tableau is connected to.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 you can make customized SQL in tableau too. So it's not only limited to which RDBMS tableau is connected to but I would say the language is very similar.

Comment: @CodyGray I mostly agree.  I think most formula questions (including the [21K excel-formula questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-formula)) are also often near-duplicates that are barely search-able and unlikely to benefit anyone other than the asker.  Maybe we have an extradition treaty with SuperUser and can send the good ones there.

Comment: Sure, we'd have to ask on [Meta Super User](https://meta.superuser.com) to confirm that Tableau usage questions are on-topic there. Aside from general usage questions, then, I'm not really clear on which other types of questions you think would be on-topic here but *not* be about the Tableau API. Do you still think we need to disambiguate [tableau-api]?

Comment: @Cody Gray I'm not sure what you mean by "the Tableau API". There's a [Tableau Server REST API](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api.htm) (haven't used it, seems to be for automating various Tableau Server tasks) but there is a [variety](https://www.tableau.com/developer/tools) of developer tools and APIs for interacting with Tableau.  (I've used TabPy and RServe in the past.). Maybe it's fine for now, but if someone has questions about the Javascript API (e.g., trying to embed viz in my web app) then that would seem like a different tag to me.  ...

Comment: ...I'm not saying you should create tags for all these developer tools in advance.  Maybe just call it [tableau-developer-tools] and wiki says that it covers any of the extensions listed [here](https://www.tableau.com/developer/tools)?

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 can you weight in here? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400683/792066

Answer (score 7):

Questions about *using* Tableau are off-topic here. It is a data visualization tool, and unrelated to programming.

The only questions about Tableau that are on-topic here are those about the API, which is the only part that is related to programming within the scope described in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

As such, I've eliminated the [tableau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableau) tag, renaming it to [tableau-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableau-api). We have no need for a generic [tableau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableau) tag here. All "connections" are preserved, as tag synonyms have been created. No bookmarks or anything else will break.

The tag rename and updates to the wiki are intended to help stem the tide of blatantly off-topic Tableau questions, which will honestly take us years to clean up.

Comment: I don't agree with this at all! You can do SQL in Tableau, you can make advanced database connections, connect it with python etc. And calculated fields, guess that's not considered as programming language together with table and LOD expressions? I think there should be a tag for Tableau-formulas and _maybe_ for visualization. Right now, this made me to loose a lot of respect for the stack community. Have there been a discussion with the community? The request for Tableau-API doesn't necessarily mean we should replace or remove the Tableau tag.

Comment: If you're doing SQL, then it doesn't matter that you happen to be doing it in Tableau. You just tag it [[tag:sql]]. (Unless Tableau has its own dialect, but said elsewhere it didn't.) Tags don't describe the context or milieu of a question; they only describe its *contents*. Writing formulas in a user-mode app is not really programming, and certainly doing visualization in an off-the-shelf data visualization app is not programming. This is a programming Q&A site. If you're looking for a general community about data science and visualization, maybe [DataScience.SE] would be a better fit?

Comment: I can understand the challenge with these software tools as they're lean toward graphical usage rather then pure coding (VizQL is the underlying programming language). In such a case, probably excel formulas and visualization in excel should be moved or removed too as they are made in a graphical interface rather than in an editor (like STATA vs MATLAB). As programs develops to be more interchangeable with each other the definition might be broaden for the on-topic... One way is to move to the Data Science another is to structure up the current tags. I still think SO should be the place to go.

Comment: It's the tableau-api only about the rest api, or any programmable interface that tableau offers?

Comment: This is really no different than Excel, which is explicitly _on topic_ for advanced programmatic usages.  See, for example, the strong consensus on [Are Excel formulas on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261875/176071).  This needs to be reconsidered.