# Decision criteria for granting/rejecting requests about combined <=> split tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-hierarchy

**Tldr:**

[Burninate request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071) has a similar decision making criteria. Can we have a similar criteria for splitting or combining tags?

---

Combined tag is a hyphenated join of two or more tags. Eg: [java-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-date),[database-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-triggers), [javascript-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-objects),[google-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api). Split tag is a un-hyphenated tag used along with a standalone language or platform tag. Eg: [facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook)+[api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api),[javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)+[arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays),[c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)+[pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointer).

A lot of synonym-requests, retag-requests or merging requests are about combo vs split tags.

- [Regarding the [java-date] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371655)
- [Tag request: tableau-api](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251957)
- [Is the "api" tag a too broad one, and a candidate for burninating?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272013)

**Why a decision criteria?**

These requests are handled without a clear decision making criteria. This makes whether a request is granted or rejected to chance, just a single criteria, mood of the moderator visiting the issue or the  completely random set of users visiting the tag request and their inclinations, time or date of the post  or other unknown factors. I'm sure moderators and other users are doing what they think is best, but without the well established criteria, most of them may change with different set of users, moderators or year of the post.

It would be better to have a clear well defined criteria(chosen by the community) to decide on which direction to take giving weight to each criteria. This will leave randomness and chance out of the decision making process.

What are the factors to consider when making such a decision?

Comment: The answer below is my opinion. The question however is unbiased and intended to as many opinion as possible to create a canonical "factors to consider"  and "general consensus"

Comment: Any reason for the downvotes? Do you not want to discuss the issue at all?  Or  do you not want a well defined criteria? Or is the question unclear or too broad? Or Should I have answered later allowing for discussion?

Comment: Don't know about others but I just downvoted because you guys are being really annoying lately discussing tags all the time using some kind of weird jargon

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks. You also have a +1 on your comment(not me yet). At least now I know it's not about my  question in particular.

Comment: I'm just not sure what problem, if any, this is trying to solve. It smells a lot like bikeshedding.

Comment: @ivarni This started because one user decided to branch all tags in a language into these long ultra specific tags. I was against it giving [reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400126). But the user challenged  me to provide a canonical q/a and Since I couldn't find one,  And I saw a lot of similar issues https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371655 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251957 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272013 for/against depending on the mod visiting the request/other factors. I thought it would be better to have a clear well defined criteria

Comment: @oguzismail I plan to do that. But still, this question is independent from that issue. A well defined criteria will help a long way in merging/retagging/synonym requests.

Comment: I don't think you understand the issue with this post. If I was given the privilege to make tag edits, propose and vote for tag synonyms, request tag burnination, etc., I don't think I have to acquaint myself with a terminology invented by literally who in order to be able to participate in discussions related to the proper use of those privileges. Again, I don't think this discussion is going anywhere.

Comment: @oguzismail If you understand, what terminology would you use for differentiating those two examples in the question? I thought about it long. Combo seems to be well known, but builder ... no. I thought about lego tags... but couldn't come up with a decent name. But I think the rest are clear enough.

Comment: @oguzismail - if we are talking about terminology here, would using "individual" instead of "brick" or "lego" suffice? As in [tag:git] [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266221/can-we-get-rid-of-git-something-tags). And "sub-tags" instead of "combo"/"combined" as in the [one about inheritance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262823/wouldnt-tag-inheritance-make-sense)?

Comment: How is this question related to [meta-tag:tag-hierarchy]?

Comment: Related [Combination tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278718/1595451)

Comment: @TheMaster Have you reviewed the tag excerpt of [meta-tag:tag-hyerarchy]?

Comment: Yes and I believe it is relevant.

Comment: So you are aware of "Tags on Stack Overflow aren't hierarchically ordered (and, in all likelihood, will never be - several proposals have been made already)". Good.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

The following factors can be used as criteria for NOT splitting a combined tag:

- Do subject matter experts agree a combined tag is warranted?
- Are the number of watchers in the combined tag enough?
- Couldn't the split tags describe the same concept satisfactorily?
- Are the individual(split) tags ambiguous and whether the ambiguity of splitted tag demonstrated by significant amount of users mis-tagging?
- Was the combined tag tagged uniformly by all users and the top 5 user contribution not exceed 20%?<sup>[SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1264912/1557927/percent-of-users-who-added-this-tag)</sup>

If the answer to ALL the above  questions is yes, then the combined tag  should not be split, else the tag should be split.